# Run different quantity observables sequentially

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method like this

```
    public void loadData(String city) {
    mWeatherDataSource.getWeatherData(city)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<WeatherResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<WeatherResponse> weatherResponses) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }
            });
}
```

and

```
public Single<List<WeatherResponse>> getWeatherData(String city) {
    return mApiService.getDataWeather(city, API_KEY);
}
```

That is working fine, but I want that loadData to work with `String... city` (or List) parameter, that runs `getWeatherData` more than once.

The result must be combined (for example):

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(List<WeatherResponse> weatherResponses) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this way:

1. Use `fromArray` operator to emit to the stream each city from the `String.. cities` array;
2. Use `flatMapSingle` operator to call your API for each city emitted
3. Use `flatMap` and `fromIterable` to get the retrieved list of WeatherResponse and emit one by one in the stream
4. Use `toList` operator to group all of them into a single list

```
    public void loadData(String... cities) {
        Observable.fromArray(cities)
                .flatMapSingle((Function<String, SingleSource<List<WeatherResponse>>>) city -> getWeatherData(city))
                .flatMap((Function<List<WeatherResponse>, ObservableSource<WeatherResponse>>) Observable::fromIterable)
                .toList()
                .subscribe(list -> {
                    // do whatever with your single list with all items
                });
    }
```